# How to avoid parsing "\" in JSON.parse () method

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, escaping, stringify

I'm trying to parse JSON to JS object, but i have problem with one property, which in value always contains "\" character and four characters after. E.g. string looks something like that:

```
"key": "Z13g\u003d"
```

Once I parse it i get:

```
"key": "Z13g="
```

Is there any easy way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why is that a problem in the first place? `\u003d` is a way you can express a `=` in a JSON string. Perhaps your problem is failing to escape the slash when you created the JSON in the first place?

Comment: `\u003d` is one way to represent the `=` character in JSON. The parser is doing its job correctly.

Comment: @Quentin First example is how original string looks like and second how it looks after parsing back to the javascript object.

Comment: @cdhowie The problem is that \u003d is part of my key, i don't want to parse it, it should stay as it is.

Comment: @DanZawadzki — I asked why parsing escaped unicode characters in JSON was a problem, not what you meant.

Comment: @DanZawadzki then whatever thing outputs the JSON should produce `"Z13g\\u003d"`. If you *parse* something, it won't stay as it is.

Comment: @DanZawadzki — Then you are generating the JSON incorrectly in the first place. You need to fix the tool that generates the JSON instead of trying to hack the parser to cope with a data format that isn't real JSON.

Comment: `\u003d` is one character not 6. It like `\n`, `\t`...

Comment: @Quentin I'm not generating this key. I'm getting it from the server side, where i don't have access.

Comment: @DanZawadzki — Then you need to write a custom parser for the JSON-like-but-not-JSON data format you are trying to parse. (It might be easier to get whomever is writing the data format to fix it). (That assumes that you aren't breaking the data somehow while retrieving it).

Comment: @DanZawadzki What evidence do you have that `Z13g=` is *not* the correct key? It sounds like you think there is a problem where there isn't one. `Z13g\u003d` would be a particularly odd key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a string like "\u003d" in JavaScript, it's indistinguishable from its parsed string "=". Even the `String.replace` function won't find the `\` character in the string.

However, if you are truly trying to represent a string that includes the backslash character, you need to escape it with another backslash.

Whereas `"\u003d"` represents the string value `"="`, `"\\u003d"` represents the string value `"\u003d"`.

However, things get more complicated when you invoke `JSON.parse`; since it's parsing the string value again, it'll transform `"\\u003d"` to `"="`.

To get around this, you need to double-escape the backslash, so you'll have a string value of `"\\\\u003d"`. The parser will transform that into `"\u003d"` instead of `"="`.

```js
console.log(JSON.parse("\"\u003d\"")); //    "\u003d" -> "="
console.log(JSON.parse("\"\\u003d\"")); //   "\\u003d" -> "="
console.log(JSON.parse("\"\\\\u003d\"")); // "\\\\u003d" -> "\u003d"
```